# Attempting to understand handling regular expressions with php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make sense of handling regular expression with php.  So far my code is:
PHP code:

```
$string = "This is a 1 2 3 test.";

$pattern  = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]$/';
$match = preg_match($pattern, $string);

echo "string: " . $string . " regex response: " , $match;
```

Why is $match always returning 0 when I think it should be returning a 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]` means *one character which is alphanumeric or "." or " "*. You will want to repeat this pattern:

```
$pattern  = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]+$/';
                            ^
                      "one or more"
```

*Note: you don't need to escape `.` inside a character group.*

Comment: Tremble in fear of my 4 second lead! :P

Comment: @alex 4 seconds to add an explanation... ;o)

Comment: You may not _need_ to escape the period in the character group, but it still works that way as well as making the programmer's intent obvious so keep doing it. It is so very easy to write impenetrable regexen so this is one case where concision isn't your friend.

Comment: @Rob On the other hand, you can also get confused over whether the backslash is supposed to be matched or is just supposed to escape. It's a mess either way if you ask me, and I like to err on the side of conciseness.

Comment: @deceze, *smile* Please pity the poor programmer who comes after you. ("We must never program for ourselves but for those who come after and must maintain our code.")

Comment: @Rob As I said, the confusion can go both ways and it really depends on the state of mind you're in which one is less confusing. Since I do not know the state of mind of my successor, I can hardly accommodate everybody.

Comment: Well, after dabbling with regex for a bit I am finding my regex to be a bit buggy.  I would like to check for at-least 1 alpha character in the beginning than allow for alphanumeric, \s, and \.

Comment: @deceze ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s\.]{1,}[a-zA-Z]$ seems to work, but that allows unlimited spaces and periods in the middle when it should only allow two spaces,one in the beginning and end of the middle while allowing a period if needed.

Comment: @deceze ^([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?(?: [a-zA-Z]+(?:\.)?)*)$ works quite well.  There really is no formal way to write names so validating people names is moot, but allow "proper" characters used in people names is what I am validating for.

Comment: @dotted Wait, you're trying to validate people's names with a Regex? Stop it, please. Even within the English language there are so many unusual names (think of the O'Connors for example), but worldwide there are so many different names, you'll most certainly piss somebody off someday. Overvalidation is never good, and people will input nonsense anyway if they want to.

Comment: @deceze I see your points.  I will just set the field to required and check for vulnerabilities using codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you're pattern is saying:

- `'/`: Start the expressions
- `^`: Beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\. ]`: Any one alphanumeric character, period or space (you should actually be using `\s` for spaces *if* your intention is to match any whitespace character).
- `$`: End of the string
- `/'`: End the expression

So, an example of a string that would yield a match result is:

`$string = 'a'`

Of other note, if you're actually trying to get the matches from the result, you'll want to use the third parameter of `preg_match`:

`$numResults = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);`

Comment: You may want to differiate between `/` (delimiter) and `^` (start anchor) as your example says that together they mean beginning of string. Also, the OP should only use `\s` for spaces if they intend to match all the whitespace characters (sometimes they don't). Fix that and you have my +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

You need a quantifier on the end of your character class, such as `+`, which means *match 1 or more times*.

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/tXlex).